# How to solve for a set of Orthogonal Functions?

Tags: functions

The Hermite Gauss modes are said to be orthogonal, since the integral between any two modes is zero.

I am interested in similar looking "stretched-out" versions of the hermite modes constructed from different time-shifted Gaussian curves, and would like to find a basis of orthogonal states.

So for example:

[image]

How can I find the set of modes that forms an orthogonal set from this?

EDIT:
To give a bit more context to the motivation for wanting such a thing: I work in a physics lab that is using "Hermite-Gauss" modes for experiments. (A piece of electronics is used that carves the amplitude of light to have these pulse shapes.) The only thing we really need are a set of "orthogonal functions" such that $\int f_m(x) f_n(x) dx = 0$. These Hermite modes are orthogonal but are tricky to make in a lab. Much easier to generate are a sequence of gaussian pulses that are separated in time and have some phase. But is there an obvious way that I can create a set of "orthogonal modes" from just time-separated gaussians in which I only change the amplitude, and phase?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to convey in these graphics and in the text accompanying them. I look at them as "caricatural" Hermite-Gaussian functions : we recognize the general shape... Do you want to accentuate the peaks ?

Comment: Your graphics can be captured by a **convolution** of a gaussian signal $f$ with for example a kind of "comb" made of Dirac peaks like for your third figure $f \star (\delta_{-1}-\delta_{0}+\delta_{1})$ on which you can work using the Fourier Transform.

Comment: @JeanMarie, thanks for the feedback.  The key is that these functions need to be orthogonal, and I'm trying to work out a general way of writing an infinite set of functions that has this kind of shape.

Comment: (To make the motivation more clear, I'm adding an extra paragraph to the question to make it more clear.)

Comment: @JeanMarie, new edit is added now if it helps

Comment: Given a set of $n$ function one can create a linear combinations of them forming orthogonal family. This is called "Gram-Schmidt" orthonormalization , see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: @Salcio, I'm not sure how that method is useful for this particular case.

Comment: Do you know **Hadamard matrices** (most of them $2^n \times 2^n$) ? Their columns are orthogonal. If you **convolve** any of its columns by a gaussian pulse (or, in a discrete setting, a certain sequence mimicking it like the $k$th line of Pascal triangle), you would get such a family of orthogonal functions.